# useReducer in useContext not saving state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, use-context, use-reducer

I am trying to fetch data from my database and then using useReducer if the fetch is successful I then want to return it as state so I can pass it down to components.

I have console.log'd req.data and it is fetching the correct data however it isn't saving to state when I return the value in the reducer.

The state is supposed to be an array of objects.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const OrganisationsContext = createContext()

export const OrganisationsContextProvider = ( { children }) => {
    const initState = []

    const organisationsReducer = (state, action) => {
        console.log(state)
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
                return [...state, action.payload]
            case 'FETCH_ERROR':
                throw new Error(action.payload)
            default:
                return state
        }   
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const initFetch = async () => {
            try {
                const req = await axios.get('/api/fetch_organisations')
                organisationsDispatch({action: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: req.data})
            } catch (err) {
                organisationsDispatch({action: 'FETCH_ERROR', payload: err})
            }
        }
        initFetch()
    }, [])

    const [organisations, organisationsDispatch] = useReducer(organisationsReducer, initState)

    return (
        <OrganisationsContext.Provider value={{organisations, organisationsDispatch}}>
            {children}
        </OrganisationsContext.Provider>
   

 )
}
```

Comment: You dispatch `{ action: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' }`, it should be `{ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' }`

Comment: ahhhhhhh yes! - thankyou